# KineticJS: Hide content that overflows the layer

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to add an image to the canvas but to limit it to the size of the layer that it puts it in. I set `width` and `height` for the layer but still it does not do what I want. Why is there a width and a height if the content is visible outside the borders anyway?

Is there a solution to limit the content inside the container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *You can hide the content that overflows a Kinetic Image object in several ways*

A clarification:  All kineticJS layers are always the same size as the stage (not changeable)

But, you can put an image in a KineticJS image object and then manipulate the image.

**Solution#1: Use the image objects `offset` property:**

You can use the KineticJS image object like a viewport into a larger image using the `offset` property.  This method is useful if you later want to move the viewport to another portion of the original image.

**Solution#2: Use the image objects `crop` property:**

You can crop a larger original image to fit into a smaller KineticJS image object.  This method is useful if you want to permanently view a cropped portion of the original image.  BTW, this method is also useful if you want to scale the cropped portion.

When you add the `crop` property to a KineticJS Image object the original image is cropped according to your specifications.   This will let you keep the desired part of the original image and crop away the undesired portion.

[image]

```
kImage=new Kinetic.Image({
    image:img,
    x:30,
    y:30,
    width:110,
    height:110,
    crop: {
        x: 150,
        y: 122,
        width: 110,
        height: 110
    }
});
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/KbESf/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 300,
        height: 150
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var kImage;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        addCroppedImage();
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/faces.png";

    function addCroppedImage(){

            kImage=new Kinetic.Image({
                image:img,
                x:30,
                y:30,
                width:110,
                height:110,
                crop: {
                    x: 150,
                    y: 122,
                    width: 110,
                    height: 110
                }
            });
            layer.add(kImage);
            layer.draw();
        }

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <p>Cropped image on Kinetic layer</p>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p>Original Image</p>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/faces.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for :) the `crop` property